# UrlPathEncode in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding, url-encoding

I'm trying to encode Unicode characters in a URL in my Silverlight project. I want to use `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334714/url-unicode-characters-encoding)

However, *this* version of the `HttpUtility` class resides in `System.Web` which is not a Silverlight assembly.

There's a number of `HttpUtility` classes out there, but I can't find a Silverlight version that allows me to do the specific encoding `UrlPathEncode` provides.

Is there a Silverlight assembly I am missing that provides this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it, but maybe the method [Uri.EscapeUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx) can do what you want. It is available in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [Mono implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpUtility.cs) of the HttpUtility class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps I was not clear enough that I *only* want to encode particular unicode characters -- that is to say, *not* `/`, `?` and so on. That method *will* replace those characters.

Comment: @tnw - Ah right. The Mono implementation might help (I've updated the answer). From a quick skim, I couldn't see anything in there that wouldn't work in Silverlight.