# Encode unicode characters in URL using PHP?

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to encode a feed's URLs, which unfortunately contain Unicode characters. My feed reader doesn't support this.

My knowledge in php is limited and my basic approach failed when it encountered a French character ç. Clearly listing each character is slow and too much work:

```
    public function encodeUmlauts($req_url) {
        $req_url = str_replace("ö", urlencode("ö"), $req_url);
        $req_url = str_replace("ü", urlencode("ü"), $req_url);
        $req_url = str_replace("ä", urlencode("ä"), $req_url);
        $req_url = str_replace("Ö", urlencode("Ö"), $req_url);
        $req_url = str_replace("Ü", urlencode("Ü"), $req_url);
        $req_url = str_replace("Ä", urlencode("Ä"), $req_url);
        $req_url = str_replace("ß", urlencode("ß"), $req_url);

        return $req_url;
    }
```

I assume something can be done with `urlencode` and/or `parse_url`, but I don't see an obvious solution.

What I'm looking for is similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334714/url-unicode-characters-encoding), but for PHP.

Comment: `print urlencode("garçon");`  will output `gar%C3%A7on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will urlencode all non-ascii characters in the URL string:

```
$url = preg_replace_callback('/[^\x20-\x7f]/', function($match) {
    return urlencode($match[0]);
}, $url);
```