# .NET 6 WebApi can't process HttpHeader with special characters

Tags: java, c#, .net, http-headers, webapi

We discovered a rather strange behavior in all of our .NET 6 Services recently. We receive a bunch of custom HTTP Headers from a Java API Gateway, which isn't in our control at all, but we can talk to the maintainer. However, as long as all values are not special ones (like ä,ö,ü) everything works as expected, but if there is any of those mentioned (and probably more), the services DOES NOTHING at all. The Gateway eventually returns a **400 BAD REQUEST** Status code and that's it.

We already tried to activate the UseConnectionLogging option, but still nothing appears in the console.

```
options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(listenOptions =>
{
    listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging();
});
```

Worth mentioning that we are listening on a specific port, but still not results in the log.

`options.ListenAnyIP(8080, listenOptions => listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging());`

We are using Serilog for all the custom logs with the lowest possible LogLevel, but well again, nothing shows up. It seems that the services aren't event called, but all the existing Java services are working without an issue.

However, if they send the request without a special character, everything gets processed nicely and the console log is full of logs as expected.

Any tips on this?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334714/url-unicode-characters-encoding?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually we managed to solve this issue via setting the encoding of the Http Headers to UTF-8. I find it quiet interesting, because UTF-8 should be the default value anyways. We have no idea why it‘s not working without setting it implicitly, but until now we haven’t had any side effects.

[MSDN Article - KestrelServerOptions.RequestHeaderEncodingSelector Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.requestheaderencodingselector?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-server-kestrel-core-kestrelserveroptions-requestheaderencodingselector)